# Remove % on symfony translated text

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm translating some texts on symfony this way

```
expired.password.body: 'Dear %name% %surname%,<br><br>Your password has expired.'
```

and this is the translation code

```
$email_params = [
                'name' => $user_to_change_password->getName(),
                'surname' => $user_to_change_password->getSurname()
            ];

$body = $this->translator->trans('expired.password.body', $email_params, 'emails');
```

then  the text is translated and the parameters are correct but the % are still in the trandlated text

```
Dear %foo_name% %bar_surname%
```

I easy to solve with `str_replace` but I think that I should making something wrong on the translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony's translator documentation, they are pointing at the fact that the keys of the argument defining the translation parameters should actually contains the percentage:

> ```php
> use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatableMessage;
>
> // the first argument is required and it's the original message
> $message = new TranslatableMessage('Symfony is great!');
> // the optional second argument defines the translation parameters and
> // the optional third argument is the translation domain
> $status = new TranslatableMessage('order.status', ['%status%' => > > $order->getStatus()], 'store');
> ```

*<sup>Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translatable-objects</sup>*

---

So, your code should read:

```php
$email_params = [
  '%name%' => $user_to_change_password->getName(),
  '%surname%' => $user_to_change_password->getSurname()
];

$body = $this->translator->trans(
  'expired.password.body', 
  $email_params, 
  'emails'
);
```